# Why using "Cast" on teradata is faster in VARCHAR?

Tags: database, casting, teradata, database-administration

Why is my query faster when I use the "CAST" on VARCHAR?

Comment: You need to show details, as it stands this is not answerable.

Comment: understand, when possible show more details.

Comment: Which CAST & where it is used?

Comment: Changed wording.